# Python - selenium unable to get element text with PhantomJS

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I can get all the text inside the other `td`s, except for `td` with `class="datapid"`

```
  <tr>
     <td class="cregion">JP</td>
     <td class="datacompany"><a href="/company/10644-tecmo">Tecmo</a></td>
     <td class="datapid">P99-00001</td>
     <td class="datapid">4960677070033</td>
     <td class="cdate">02/06/03</td>
     <td class="datarating">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
```

I'm using selenium with PhantomJS 2.1.1:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(
"c:/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs.exe")
```

Trying to get the fields, but only the `datapid` field is blank:

```
    cregions = driver.find_elements(
    By.CLASS_NAME, "cregion")
    for region in cregions:
        regions.append(region.text)

    datacompanies = driver.find_elements(
    By.CLASS_NAME, "datacompany")
    for company in datacompanies:
        publishers.append(company.find_element(By.XPATH, "a").text)

    datapids = driver.find_elements(
    By.CLASS_NAME, "datapid")
    for i in range(0, (len(datapids))):
        if i % 2:
            pids.append(datapids[i].text)  //datapids[i].text = ''
```

Comment: what happens with  for pid in datapids:
        pids.append(pid.text)

Answer (score 1):

After maximizing the windows:

```
driver.maximize_window()
```

now I can get the text inside the `div`.

I think it is because that the `webdriver` is not simply reading the source code, but getting it from a windows. If the `node` is outside the window, it could not be read by `webdriver`